# Несколько Form и подключение к базе данных

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, mvp

В программе несколько форм и каждой так или иначе нужна БД (через класс посредник) для наполнения или записи полученных данных.

Вопрос в том, как организовать работу с БД. В смысле подключения. Каждый раз для команды делать новое подключение. Держать один экземпляр в рамках класса посредника. Или иметь только одно соединение на все приложение и обращаться к БД через него.

Сейчас у меня третий вариант. Но выходит запутанная штука. Будто создаешь еще одну надстройку над OleDbConnection. По сути, с теми же методами. Только возвращающими результаты от оригинального OleDbConnection.

**UPDATA:**

Нашел следующую вещь ([на msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ole-db-odbc-and-oracle-connection-pooling))

> Поставщик данных .NET Framework для OLE DB автоматически создает пулы
>   соединений, используя пулы сеанса OLE DB.

Выходит можно и нужно делать новое соединение каждый раз? Если есть автоматический пул. Правда непонятно, надо ли что-то явно указывать для этого.

Comment: Эта тема с Пулом подключений уже много раз тут обсуждалась, вы легко можете найти дубликаты. Но да, вы пришли к верному выводу с пулом подключений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот что выяснил.

> чтобы осуществлять связь между базой данных и приложением на C#
>   необходим посредник. И именно таким посредником является технология
>   ADO.NET ([источник](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/1.1.php))
>
> в ADO.NET используется механизм пула подключений ([источник](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.4.php))
>
> ADO.NET работает с OleDb ([источник](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dw70f090(v=vs.98)))

И наконец, по примеру [источника](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.4.php) проделал массовое открытие-закрытие в цикле и делал снимок памяти. Как и утверждает цитата в UPDATE моего вопроса - пул создается автоматически. Как только вы изменяете строку подключения - создается новый пул. Подробнее по источнику из первого предложения.

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            string connectionString = 
                   "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=Название.accdb";
            for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            {
                using (OleDbConnection connection = new 
                       OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}) {1}", i, connection.State));
                }
                Console.Write("Pause");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            using (OleDbConnection connection = 
                   new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=ДругоеНазвание.accdb"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}) {1}", 
                        "Другая строка подключения:", connection.State()));
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
```

Согласно коду, после каждого закрытия (благодаря using) была пауза. В которую я делал снимок памяти. Пока строка подключения не меняется, используются те же ресурсы. Как только поменяли строку подключения, резкий скачек (создалось новое подключение и новый пул).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому, буду создавать новое подключение для каждой команды. Поскольку моя строка подключения не изменится в течении сеанса программы. Для извлечения строки подключения использую параметры уровня приложения ([источник](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings)).

Comment: Если у тебя куча форм, то используй  Внедрение зависимостей (Dependency Injection) например IoC-контейнер Ninject. Создаешь репозиторий, в нем контект БД, и функциональность для работы с БД. И неявно среда исполнения пробрасывает твои репозитории в нужные формы.( или даже сам контект данных). Для работы с БД лучше использовать ADO.NET Entity Framework / (Core).